# How to pass value by HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I need to access a page with login session required through `HttpWebRequest`. Therefore, I need to find a way to pass value to the page in order to login, or directly assign the login status value. I have followed the answers of similar questions - use cookie, which is as follows:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(context.JobDetail.JobDataMap("url") + "/page.aspx"), HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
request.ContentLength = 1
Dim cookie = New Cookie("Login", "Y")
request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie)
```

But none of them tell how to get the cookie value on the other side (i.e. page.aspx.vb). Here is the code that I have tried which is not working though:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MsgBox(Request.Cookies("Login"))
    Session("Login") = Request.Cookies("Login")

    If Session("Login") <> "Y" Then
        Response.Redirect("loginFail.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

`MsgBox(Request.Cookies("Login"))` is just for testing, and it shows an empty box.

Comment: *”or directly assign the login status value”* so I can log into your online banking system by just setting “loggedin = true” in a cookie??

Comment: As to your problem, try putting the uri into the cookiecontainer add method, or put it in the cookie